Can one use "they" instead of "he or she"
For example, in the following sentence:

If a student is caught cheating, he or she will be immediately eliminated.
If a student is caught cheating, they will be immediately eliminated.


See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429451/singular-they-how-old-are-is-they

Why do they migrate this type of question?

I agree with Michael ... this is a duplicate, not a candidate for migration. The duplicate answers clearly: many freely accept the use of singular they for situations where gender is unknown, likely to be mixed, or withheld for some reason. But some institutions buck the trend. So the question really becomes 'Do the authorities relevant to my situation endorse the use of singular they'? Not a general English question.

Thank you for pointing out the duplicate. This one can be deleted. Thanks for the help

A long-standing solution is to pluralize the subject: "If students are caught cheating, they will be immediately eliminated."

@PeterShor et al, agreed: Migration of a duplicate just makes a mess. I suppose the 14-yr-old duplicate can't itself be migrated?

@YosefBaskin - it seems a little extreme - do they face a firing squad, or maybe a gallows?

@MichaelHarvey Metaphorically so ... from some contest?

The disciplinary action I hear most often in these situations is He was disqualified. A team or competitor can be eliminated in a competition, e.g the European football championship

Yes, one can.
If you look up 'they' in a dictionary you'll learn that it is used as a singular pronoun for someone whose gender is unknown or unspecified. So, when speaking about a hypothetical person who could be either gender as in your example, 'they' is ideal. Saying "he or she" is fairly common, but increasingly criticised as it could be interpreted as 'he' is the default or most likely audience and 'she' is a possible afterthought tagged onto the end.
